# MongoDB count number of times where a field is true using aggregation framework

Tags: java, mongodb, count, aggregation-framework

**Synopsis**

Trying to count the number of times a user with the field 'seen' equals 'false'

**(Mail) Collection Example**

```
{
 to : "jimmy",
 from : "johny",
 message : "Hey",
 seen: false
},
{
 to : "jimmy",
 from : "Maggy",
 message : "Hello",
 seen: true
},
{
 to : "jimmy",
 from : "Sam",
 message : "How are you?",
 seen: false
},
{
 to : "jimmy",
 from : "johny",
 message : "It's me again",
 seen: false
}
```

**Java Method w/Mongo Aggregation**

```
  //WHERE 'to' EQUALS 'jimmmy'
  //COUNT 'seen' EQUALS 'false'
```

**What I've tried**

```
    public int getTotalUnseen(String toUser){

AggregateIterable<Document> iterable = db.getCollection("mail").aggregate(asList(
        new Document("$match", new Document("to", "jimmy")),
        new Document("$group", new Document("_id", "$seen").append("count", new Document("$sum", 1)))));

    }
```

**Desired Result**

```
int x = getTotalUnseenCount("jimmy");
System.out.println("Result : "+ x);


//Result : 3
```

Comment: Why not filter the field in the first place?

Comment: @mszymborski could you supply an example

Comment: `db.mail.find({"to": "jimmy", "seen": false}).count()` - isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah think this will work. I was looking to figure out how this simple scenerio is done using the aggregation framework

Comment: Ah, then you can simply apply the same document in the `$match` stage, and then give `_id: 1`, the sum seems correct. Of course you'd have to extract the only result from the iterable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("to").is("jimmy").and("seen").is(true));    
mongoTemplate.count(query, "mail");
```